# How can we add an image in Toolbar repeatedly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitoolbar, ipad

Please any one can give an idea for an image adding repeatedly in X axis.
Thanks in advance

Comment: hi use category files to add the image....

Comment: Elaborate what you are trying to do

Comment: i have a small jpg image and that added repeatedly for toolbar backgroud

Comment: i will add a small image that add to repeatedly in toolbar backgroud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi here is the code to add image to the UIToolBar by category....

**.h file :**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIToolbar (AddtitionalFuntionality)

+(void)setToolbarBack:(NSString*)bgFilename toolbar:(UIToolbar*)toolbar;

@end
```

**.m file:**

```
#import "UIToolbar+AddtitionalFuntionality.h"

@implementation UIToolbar (AddtitionalFuntionality)

+(void)setToolbarBack:(NSString*)bgFilename toolbar:(UIToolbar*)bottombar {  
    // Add Custom Toolbar
    UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:bgFilename]];
    iv.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, bottombar.frame.size.width, bottombar.frame.size.height);
    iv.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    // Add the tab bar controller's view to the window and display.
    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] intValue] >= 5)
        [bottombar insertSubview:iv atIndex:1]; // iOS5 atIndex:1
    else
        [bottombar insertSubview:iv atIndex:0]; // iOS4 atIndex:0
    bottombar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}

@end
```

**The call statement will be....**

```
[UIToolbar setToolbarBack:@"tool-bar.png" toolbar:toolBarTop];
```

the source code of the category [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9bcgh3lan9luies/pDLkgZo-vG?m)

link to blog: [Site](http://arunios.blogspot.in/2012/09/uitoolbar-categories.html)